# Measuring AC motor load with CT clamp

Tags: arduino, adc, current-measurement

I am trying to measure the load in an AC induction motor with a current clamp and ADC. When using a clamp multimeter I get a value of 3.6 A when the 5.5 kW three-phase motor is running without load.

When I connect an SCT-013-000 clamp to a ADS1015 I get OK readings when the motor is running in a star connection, but as soon as the star-delta starter switches over to delta the reading starts jumping around. Since the clamp multimeter can read it, I assumed a CT could also.

The SCT-013-000 clamp is connected with one wire to GND and one to the ADS1015. When the motor is not running the ADC reading is a steady 0. When the motor is running in a star connection, the readings are stable.

In delta connection the reading is unstable. The values are nonsense since the lowest value recorded by the ADC over 250 ms is the lowest value the ADC can report: -2048. The maxValue recorded fluctuates somewhere around 300-400. In around one in five serial prints the minValue is not -2048.

```
  #include "ADS1X15.h"
  ADS1015 ADS( 0x48 );
  ADS.begin();
  ADS.setGain(0);
  ...
  uint32_t start_time = 0;
  int OneSampleVolt = 2; //+/- 4.096V  1 bit = 2mV (4096*2)/4096
  float mVperAmp = 668.0/8.0; //8A corresponds 688 mV
  double AmpsRMS = 0;
  double Vrms = 0;
  int64_t maxValue = 0;
  int64_t minValue = 4096;
  int64_t Vpeak = 0;
  ...
  bladeMotorLoad  = ADS.readADC(1);
  if (millis() - start_time < 250) {
    maxValue = (bladeMotorLoad > maxValue) ? bladeMotorLoad : maxValue;
    minValue = (bladeMotorLoad < minValue) ? bladeMotorLoad : minValue;
  } else {

    Vpeak = (maxValue - minValue)/2 * OneSampleVolt;
    Vrms = Vpeak * 0.707;
    AmpsRMS = Vrms/mVperAmp;
    Serial.println("Amps RMS: " +String(AmpsRMS) + " / "+String(Vrms) + " / "+String(Vpeak) + " / "+String(minValue) + " / "+String(maxValue) );
    maxValue = 0;
    minValue = 4096;
    start_time = millis();
  }
```

Calculation for load resistor

SCT-013-000 CT 0-100A, 2000 turns

Measure 50bA RMS peak, 3.3 V AREF

Primary peak-current = RMS current × √2

Secondary peak-current = Primary peak-current / no. of turns

Ideal load resistance = (AREF/2) / Secondary peak-current
(3.3/2)/((Math.sqrt(2)*50)/2000) = 46.67 Ω = ~51 Ω

Schematic and PCB layout:

[image: Schematic for ADS1015 and CT]

[image: PCB Layout for ADS1015 and CT]

The questions I can't find answers to are:

1. Is it possible to measure the current of a AC motor in a delta configuration?
2. Have I done something wrong in the schematic or PCB layout?

**Update**

According to @greybeard the burden resistor should be connected to both ends of the CT and not in series on one end.

Updated schematic and PCB:

[image: Update Schematic for ADS1015 and CT]

[image: Update PCB Layout for ADS1015 and CT]

Comment: "*reading get weird*" and "*reading gets much higher*" are meaningless and unhelpful. Please give numbers.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have clarified somewhat. The values are nonsense since the the lowest value recorded by the ADC over 250ms is the lowest value the ADC can report; -2048. The maxValue recorded fluctuates somewhere around 300-400. At around one in five 250ms periods the minValue is not -2048.

Comment: If R23 is the CT burden resistor, it needs to be connected to both terminals of the CT - GND being the obvious choice for a reference potential.

Comment: Thank you @greybeard, I updated the question with a new schematic and pcb. Would this be correct?

Comment: GND shouldn't be used as the reference potential; it needs to be 1.65 volts. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFTl1.png <-- I've added a resistor (in red) of value typically 4k7 to protect the MCU input.